# Know how many and the name of the uncompressed files with ZipArchive

Tags: php, laravel

I am unzipping a folder that is sent to me from an API. I need to know the number of files inside this folder and the name of these files.

```
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open(realpath($path_storage)) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo(realpath(Storage::disk('public')->path($path)));
        $zip->close();
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($path . $name_file . '.' . $extension);
    }
```

This code works fine as it extracts the contents of the folder. But I need to know the number of files that the folder contained and the name of these files.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here works for me

```
            for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++)
            {
                echo 'Filename: ' . $zip->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />';
            }
```